# Does azimuthal charge symmetry on a sphere's surface imply azimuthal symmetry of potential?

Tags: electrostatics

The question in title came while I was answering the following question:

> Surface charge density $\sigma = \sigma_0\sin \theta$ is put on surface of a >sphere, radius 'a'. Find the potential inside and outside the sphere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. After all, the potential is caused by the presence of charges, so its symmetry follows the symmetry of the charge distribution. Laplace's equation in spherical coordinates will therefore be independent of $\phi$. It will therefore reduce to $$\nabla^2 V = \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial \left(r^2\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}\right)}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^2 \sin \theta} \frac{\partial \left( \sin \theta \frac{\partial V}{\partial \theta}\right)}{\partial \theta}$$